# What primary key for partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, partitioning

I have Postgres11 DB with a table with a primary key on `(a, b, c)`.

I now want to partition this table on both `a` and another column `d`. What should the primary key on the partitions be? Must I include `d`? In what position? Can I omit it to keep the index smaller?

Comment: As of Postgres 11, the partition key **has** to be part of the primary key.

Comment: Does it matter in what position it occurs?

Comment: No, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Does the position matter for how large the index will turn out to be? It seems a little wasteful to have to put these things in the index in the first place given that they can be inferred from the partitioning